# Displaying array values in a dynamic table based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

In HTML, I have an array, I wanted to display that array values in table based on condition,
array is having "No Cust" and other values. I wanted to display only other values. array size may change dynamically. So I tried the below code. It is creating the table but not displaying the text value, Kindly help

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Sample Page that Writes Out an HTML Table</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
            var text = ["No Cust", "No Cust", "20 cust", "No Cust", "30 Cust", "80 cust", "50 cust"];
            count=0;
            var text2 = "";

            for (i=0; i<7; i++) {
                if (text[i] == "No Cust") {
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    text2[count] = text[i];
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }

            document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">')

            for(j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                document.write('<tr>')
                document.write('<td> text2[j] </td>')
                document.write('</tr>')
            }

            document.write('</table>')
        </SCRIPT>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: D o n ' t  u s e  `d o c u m e n t . w r i t e`.

Comment: +1 Don't use `d o c u m e n t . w r i t e`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with single loop, like this:

```
    var text = ["No Cust", "No Cust", "20 cust", "No Cust", "30 Cust", "80 cust", "50 cust"];

    document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">');
    for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text[i] == "No Cust") {
            document.write('<tr>');
            document.write('<td>' + text[i] + '</td>');
            document.write('</tr>');
        }
    }
    document.write('</table>');
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/ynxfkqqe/1/)

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in your script. First the syntax is incorrect as other people noted. You are fixing the array's length when you don't have to. You are also matching "No Cust" unnecessarily in your filter. You are writing to the DOM multiple times, which is very expensive. Try this:

```
var text = ["No Cust", "No Cust", "20 cust", "No Cust", "30 Cust", "80 cust", "50 cust"],
    text2 = [],
    i;


for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] !== "No Cust") {
        text2.push(text[i]);
    }
}

var table = '<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">';

for (i = 0; i < text2.length; i++) {
    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<td>' + text2[i] + '</td>';
    table += '</tr>';
}

table += '</table>';

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = table;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7fbq3ps7/

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code:

```
document.write('<td> text2[j] </td>')
```

should be

```
document.write('<td>' + text2[j] + '</td>')
```

Comment: It is displaying as  +text2[j]+ in the table but not actual array value

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to display text2[j] as a static text by including it inside "'"(single quotes).
So, document.write(''+ text2[j] +'') will resolve the problem

I have restructured your for loop a bit to handle dynamic length of the array :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Sample Page that Writes Out an HTML Table</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
        var text = ["No Cust", "No Cust", "20 cust", "No Cust", "30 Cust", "80 cust", "50 cust"];
        count=0;
        var text2 = new Array();

        for (i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
            if (text[i] == "No Cust") {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                text2[count] = text[i];
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }

        document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">')

        for(j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            document.write('<tr>')
            document.write('<td>'+ text2[j] +'</td>')
            document.write('</tr>')
        }

        document.write('</table>')
    </SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

If you want to skip two loops and use one instead, below is the code :

```
 <SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
        var text = ["No Cust", "No Cust", "20 cust", "No Cust", "30 Cust", "80 cust", "50 cust"];
        document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1"   cellpadding="5">');
        for (i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
            if (text[i] != "No Cust") {
               document.write('<tr>')
               document.write('<td>'+ text[i] +'</td>')
               document.write('</tr>')
         }
       }          
    </SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is ok , but i would change some things:**

1. don't use document.write
2. why not join the array to create the table ? (join is faster&shorter than text concatenation)

---

```
var text=['No Cust','No Cust','20 cust','No Cust','30 Cust','80 cust','50 cust'],
    l=text.length,
    c=0,
    A=[];
for(;c<l;c++){
 text[c]=='No Cust'||A.push(text[c])
}
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('table')).innerHTML=
'<tbody><tr><td>'+A.join('</td></tr><tr><td>')+'</td></tr></tbody>';
```

Note: if it's a big table use `document.createDocumentFragment()`

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/5tswopt4/

if you have some questions about the code just ask.